# Make a color light

Tags: pdftex, color

So I can define a color by,

```
\definecolor{mintbg}{rgb}{.63,.79,.95}
```

which gives something like

[image]

How do I make this color a little bit lighter, is there any keyword to pass to do this?

Comment: Mixing it with `white` colour perhaps?

Comment: but why did you pick those numbers? you could use xcolor and color mixing but just increasing all three numbers will make it lighter, by definition. 0,0,0 is black and 1,1,1 is white.

Comment: I am fairly new to using latex, so I didn't know this . But I got it now, thanks everyone.

Comment: @Eular: You must restrict `\color{mintbg!40}` to a local group, i.e. `{\color{mintbg!40} ... other stuff}`, otherwise the colour definition would leak through the rest of your document until another colour is applied

Comment: `\colorlet` or `\color` depends on the where you are using the commands. `\colorlet` defines a new color, `\color` switches to a color. We need a MWE to answer why one works as expected and the other doesn't. Read the `xcolor` manual for more information about the available color definition and color usage commands.

Comment: please don't edit solutions into the question it makes it very hard to follow later. but neither of the "solutions" that you show appears in the answer or comments. you have used colorlet with the same name as the original, whereas the answer shows it defining a new name `lightmintbg` and `\color` which is also not used in the posted answer, defines the foreground colour so you have made light blue text on a light blue background.

Comment: @Schweinebacke: As far as I know `\colorlet` is only local, such the `\colorlet` definition is used in a group, applied there with the new name and is of course unknown outside of the group (environment), but at that time the colour is switched back to the old one, whereas the `\color{mintbg!40}` seems to be applied outside. But we don't know, actually

Comment: @Eular Just a guess, why your second picture did not work: In your lstings (or whatever code enevironment you use), you have probably still the original color `mintbg`. Try to replace it with `mintbg!40!white`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `\color` should be local too. I guess the difference is *defining a color* vs. *using a color*.  But we [need to see the code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to see what happens.

Comment: @Schweinebacke: Of course `\color` is local too, but if it is outside of the environment (I suppose something like that) it will have an effect on the remaining document

Answer (score 9):

It's always possible to mix an existing colour with other colours, say, white here, to make it 'slightly' lighter, if `xcolor` package is used.

The syntax for colour and mixing with `40 %` keeping of the original colour and `60 %` white content is `{\color{mintbg!40!white} ....}`, where `...` means some 'arbitrary' content. Note the `{...}` around the usage of `\color` and the content `...`, this prevents colour leaking to the rest of the document.

Using `\colorlet` seems to be easier, especially if the colour is to be used more than once, in fact, this defines a new colour, but it does not get applied directly, using `\color` is still necessary, however, with the new colour name.

See the small example below, where I used `40` as value to make the difference more outstanding visually, but `slightly` lighter is more likely to be `mintbg!80!white`, for example.

In fact, the word `white` can be omitted here, since that colour is the default then, so `\colorlet{lightmintbg}{mintbg!40}` has the same result then.(Thanks to Schweinebacke, reminding me of this!)

Other styles could be, just for completeness: `\colorlet{otherbg}{mintbg!20!blue!30!yellow}` (which is a rather awful colour, by the way)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mintbg}{rgb}{.63,.79,.95}

\colorlet{lightmintbg}{mintbg!40}
% or
%\colorlet{lightmintbg}{mintbg!40!white}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\colorbox{mintbg}{\parbox{10cm}{\blindtext}}

\colorbox{lightmintbg}{\parbox{10cm}{\blindtext}}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "always" if you spurn the one true original color package

Comment: @Schweinebacke: Thanks, I forgot about that feature and added the hint.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: "always" is `xcolor` is used ... (sorry ;-))

Comment: I have edited the question to include the results, you can see the difference

Comment: @Eular the code you posted is not at all like the code in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `rgb` model models colour with red green and blue spotlights so to make it lighter you just want to increase the brightness of each. 0,0,0 all three lights are off, so black, 1,1,1 all three lights are full on, so white.

Here I added a bit to each component

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{mintbg}{rgb}{.63,.79,.95}
\definecolor{lightmintbg}{rgb}{.67,.83,.99}


\begin{document}

\colorbox{mintbg}{\makebox(100,100){???}}

\colorbox{lightmintbg}{\makebox(100,100){???}}


\end{document}
```